# D3.js Tree - Check and set fill circle node white if no children?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How to check if node has children and set the fill of circle to white if no children?

Currently using:

```
var colourScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain(["MD", "Professional", "Leader", "Advocate", "Clinician"])
  .range(["#6695c8", "#cd3838", "#d48440", "#a8ba5f", "#63b7c0"]);

nodeUpdate.select("circle")
    .attr("r", 10)
    .attr("fill-opacity","0.7")
    .attr("stroke-opacity","1")
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return colourScale(findParent(d));
    })
    .style("stroke", function(d) {
      return colourScale(findParent(d));
    });
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4sc7moa9/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  nodeUpdate.select("circle")
    .attr("r", 10)
    .attr("fill-opacity", "0.7")
    .attr("stroke-opacity", "1")
    .style("fill", function(d) {
    console.log(d);
    return (typeof d._children !== 'undefined') ? (colourScale(findParent(d))) : '#FFF';
    })
    .style("stroke", function(d) {
    return colourScale(findParent(d));
    });
```

Edit:
The problem here is that your first node doesn't have a `_children` attribute, but a `children` one. Because children is added when clicking (_children become empty, and children take the value. Change it and it's gonna be ok)

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/35jtzv76/1/)

Comment: @IlludiumPu36 pay attention, when you click on an empty node, since it's empty _children and fill children, the node will got color
I think you need to stop interchanging children and _children, or check if it's defined AND if the length is 0
like `typeof d._children !== 'undefined' && d._children.length != 0`
(because it's check if it's defined before, it won't cause error